# Detecting and rebuilding ElasticSearch Indices

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

We want to create a function which can detect if there are differences between our intended ES types and our definitions and if it is needed to rebuild the indices.

We are generating type mappings using data annotations as per the [documentation](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/indices/put-mapping.html).

```
   [ElasticType(IdProperty = "Id", Name = "blog_post")]
    public class BlogPost
    {
        [ElasticProperty(Name = "_id", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
        public Guid id { get; set; }

        [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.String, Name = "Title", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
        public String Title { get; set; }

        [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Nested, Name = "Keywords", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
        public ICollection<Keyword> Keywords { get; set; }

        [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.String, Name = "NotSearchable", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
        public String NotSearchable { get; set; }

        [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.String, Name = "Text", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
        public String Text { get; set; }
    }
    public class Keyword
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public String Text { get; set; }
    }
```

The theory was to create a new Index and then compare the Mapping properties, and if there were any differences then we need to Rebuild the index. Below I create an empty index using the same object which I initially created the first index type.(the theory being as time passes the object may have new properties added or we may change the ElasticProperties).

```
var response = client.CreateIndex(ci => ci.Index("timbonest2").AddMapping<BlogPost>(m => m.MapFromAttributes()));
            if (response.IsValid)
            {
                var map = client.GetMapping<BlogPost>(f => f.Index("timbonest"));
                var map2 = client.GetMapping<BlogPost>(f => f.Index("timbonest3"));
            }
```

Is there a NEST method or low level method which will allow this comparison once I have the mapping collections?

Comment: `the theory being as time passes the object may have new properties added` so if I get you right, you want to avoid new fields to be added dynamically to your mapping type? If so, why don't you use the [`dynamic: strict` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html) when declaring your mapping? That would prevent new fields from creeping up into your mapping at all and not have to carve out this whole comparison process (which doesn't really belong to your business logic IMHO)...

Comment: @Val one example scenario  is the keywords collection above was not specified as Nested when the type mappings were first created in the index, thus it wasnt searchable. I want to be able to detect a difference between two versions of the mappings so i can then perform a alias and reindex function.